# expand_template with make variables

Tags: bazel

I have a seemingly simple task that is giving me a hard time: expand a template with a variable defined by the user.

I have a file (template) that has one variable I need to substitute:

```
$key_selection_color: @SELECTION_COLOR@;
```

I decided to use [`expand_template`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-skylib/blob/main/rules/expand_template.bzl) like this:

```py
expand_template(
    name = "key_colors",
    out = "_key_colors.scss",
    substitutions = {
        "@SELECTION_COLOR@": "$(FOO)",
    },
    template = "_key_colors.scss.in",
)
```

However, when I run `bazel build --define FOO=000000 //:key_colors`, `$(FOO)` doesn't get substituted and my `_key_colors.scss` file becomes:

```
$key_selection_color: $(FOO);
```

What have I done wrong and what should I do to achieve the desired behavior? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bazel-skylib implementation of this rule does not support replacing vars in the substitutions, in the same way it doesn't support expanding locations etc (at the time of writing this). It's a very light wrapper around [`ctx.actions.expand_template`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/actions#expand_template).

However, the [aspect-build/bazel-lib](https://github.com/aspect-build/bazel-lib) implementation of `expand_template` does support these substitutions. See [the docs](https://docs.aspect.build/aspect-build/bazel-lib/v0.9.6/docs/expand_make_vars-docgen.html#expand_template) for further info.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this!! It finally solved my problem here, by using `load("@aspect_bazel_lib//lib:expand_template.bzl", "expand_template")` instead of `load("@bazel_skylib//rules:expand_template.bzl", "expand_template")`.